# How can i add stciky note feature into my android application?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created an android application for note taking like notepad.

Now I want to add a sticky note feature in it so can anyone tell me how can i add this feature.

What I am trying to do is this : When user clicks on "Create Sticky Note " option then a sticky note should be created in home screen of the android phone.

I searched on google about this but it shows "how to create sticky note" as an app for android.

I want to implement it as an add-on feature for my notepad app.

Answer (score 0):

> When user clicks on "Create Sticky Note " option then a sticky note should be created in home screen of the android phone.

This is not possible.

You are welcome to create an app widget that the user can elect to put on his or her home screen, and that app widget can show "sticky notes" in whatever space the user gives to that app widget. However, the decision of whether or not to display the app widget is a decision between the user and the home screen app -- you do not get a vote.